# How can I do performance testing on Cassandra database as a manual tester?

Tags: automated-testing, manual-testing, jmeter, performance, load-testing

I need to send data on Cassandra DB and retrieve it back. I want to check how much time it will take to post data and retrieve it back.

We are not using Rest API's. There are methods(logic)only. Data get dump into Cassandra DB and retrieve when we call methods.

I need to check how much data we can save into Cassandra, and in how much time I can retrieve that data.

How can I do performance testing on Cassandra database?

Comment: Closing mafia: c'mon folks, you can't try improving the question?  Seems like a totally legit question to me.

Comment: Can you be more precise what you are trying to test? Do you have an API which writes data to Cassandra?

Answer (score 1):

Performance testing comes in two flavors:

### How long does 1 request take

### How long does 1 request take when there are also 'x' other requests

For "How long does 1 request take"

Measure the time.  Use a script or a language to write out the steps to perform the operation and add timing at the start and end to know how long it takes.

For "How long under load"

You would need to have either:

- have a bunch of manual testers, all acting at the same time - hard
- automation instead of manual testing - hard

yup, load testing is hard and not a manual thing

Comment: Is there any tool available in automation through which I can load test Cassandra DB??

Answer (score 1):

If I got your question correctly, you are trying to test the performance of Cassandra which I believe there should be good benchmarks already available for example [here](https://academy.datastax.com/planet-cassandra/nosql-performance-benchmarks) and [here](https://www.datastax.com/nosql-databases/benchmarks-cassandra-vs-mongodb-vs-hbase)

Comment: Can you please add more details instead of simply providing links? It would be more helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You can consider [Apache JMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/), JMeter is free, open source, multiprotocol modular load testing tool. You don't need to possess a lot of skills to start using it as JMeter is GUI-based and well-documented.

There is no out-of-box Cassandra support, however you can add it via the relevant [Cassandra Plugin](https://github.com/Netflix/CassJMeter/wiki/getting_started). You will be able to perform CRUD operations via Cassandra Put, Cassandra Get, Cassandra Delete, etc. samplers:

[image: JMeter Cassandra support]

Cassandra JMeter plugin can be installed using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PluginsManager/).

[image: JMeter Cassandra Support Plugins Manager]

Load test results can be visualized via [HTML Reporting Dashboard](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html).

You can quickly ramp-up in JMeter enrolling into [JMeter Academy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/learn-jmeter-for-free-launching-the-jmeter-academy) course, it should take only few hours to get ready for creating load tests.